# The code is remove the empty lines from the file from .c files and .ini files

Tags: batch-file

This code is used to replace a string within the file:

```bash
@echo off
Set _PathtoFile=D:\headercpp\revs.ini
Set _OldLine=subminor=5
Set _NewLine=subminor=6
:: End of Search parameters
Call :_Parse "%_PathtoFile%"
Set _Len=0
Set _Str=%_OldLine%
Set _Str=%_Str:"=.%987654321

:_Loop
If NOT "%_Str:~18%"=="" Set _Str=%_Str:~9%& Set /A _Len+=9& Goto _Loop
Set _Num=%_Str:~9,1%
Set /A _Len=_Len+_Num
PushD %_FilePath%
If Exist %_FileName%.new Del %_FileName%.new
If Exist %_FileName%.old Del %_FileName%.old
Set _LineNo=0
For /F "Tokens=* Eol=" %%I In (%_FileName%%_FileExt%) Do (
    Set _tmp=%%I
    Set /A _LineNo+=1
    If /I "!_tmp:~0,%_Len%!"=="%_OldLine%" (
      >>%_FileName%.new Echo %_NewLine%
    ) Else (
        If !_LineNo! GTR 1 If "!_tmp:~0,1!"=="[" Echo.>>%_FileName%.new
        SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
        >>%_FileName%.new Echo %%I
        EndLocal
    ))
Ren %_FileName%%_FileExt% %_FileName%.old
Ren %_FileName%.new %_FileName%.ini
::call :_check
if /i exist "%~1\" (set "Folder=%~1") else (exit)
PopD
Goto :EOF

:_Parse
Set _FilePath=%~dp1
Set _FileName=%~n1
Set `_FileExt`=%~x1
::Set _UpdatedFileName=Newtextupdated
Goto :EOF
```

However, the resulting output does not preserve empty lines.

How do I leave the empty lines in place?

Comment: A `for /f` loop will always omit empty lines. The only way to prevent that is to prepend each line with content. That could be done without much difficulty within the code, using either `find.exe` or `findstr.exe` together with their `/N` option. You would then remove the prepended part, as your code progresses. Please also, in future, review your own submission as you're typing it, and before you actually submit it. That code was practically unreadable, and not formatted correctly.

Comment: You change `(%_FileName%%_FileExt%)` to ('find or findstr command as already mentioned').

Comment: I told you which part to change, and the commands to use instead. I did not mention `type` or `break`, and you need to understand that is only part of the fix, you then need to adjust the output removing the prepended line numbers. You certainly cannot, and should not post that in the comment section, it should be an [Edit] to your question.